# gitlab-ci: Is there a way to visualize or simulate pipelines for different branch/tag names?

Tags: gitlab-ci

We have a fairly complex `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration. I know about the new gitlab pipeline editor, but I can't find a way to 'simulate' what jobs get picked by my `rules` depending on the branch name, tag, etc.

On our jobs, we have a `$PIPELINE` custom variable to allow us to have different pipeline 'types' by using schedules to define this var to different values, like this:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: '$PIPELINE == "regular" && ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null)'
```

or like this:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG != null'
```

Is there a way to 'simulate' a pipeline with different branch names, tags and variables so I can see what jobs get picked on each case, without actually running the pipelines (e.g. with a test tag, etc.). Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15622

Comment: Possibly relevant tool: https://github.com/umutphp/visualize-gitlabci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, but this is close, with [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#simulate-default-branch-pipeline-in-the-pipeline-editor) (August 2022):

> ### Simulate default branch pipeline in the Pipeline Editor
>
> The pipeline editor helps prevent syntax errors in your pipeline before you commit. But pipeline logic issues are harder to spot. For example, incorrect `rules` and `needs` job dependencies might not be noticed until after you commit and try running a pipeline.
>
> In this release, we’ve brought the ability to simulate a pipeline to the pipeline editor.
>
> This was previously available in limited form in the [CI Lint tool](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html#simulate-a-pipeline), but now you can use it directly in the pipeline editor. Use it to simulate a new pipeline creation on the default branch with your changes, and detect logic problems before you actually commit!
>
> [image: https://youtu.be/yYjmd-lgzMk]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/337282).